# How to extract the actual date from a string using dateparser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, datetime, tuples

**Question**

When I search for a date in a string using dateparser, I am given a tuple which includes both the date as a string and as a datetime.datetime object- I only want the string and where there are more than one, if possible, each separately.

Any ideas on how I can isolate the text from the result - removing the datetime.datetime object?

**Reason:**

I want to use the variable to then parse the word before the date found.

```
from dateparser.search import search_dates
para = search_dates("Competition opens 1/03/19 at 6:00 AM and closes 17/05/19 at 5:00 PM", settings={'STRICT_PARSING': True, 'DATE_ORDER': 'DMY'})
for x in para[0]:
    print (x)
    print(type(x))
```

What I am seeking is '1/03/19 at 6:00 AM and'

**Output:**

```
1/03/19 at 6:00 AM and
<class 'str'>
2019-03-01 06:00:00
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

**Attempts**

I have tried the following:

First:

```
from dateparser.search import search_dates
para = search_dates("Competition opens 1/03/19 at 6:00 AM and closes 17/05/19 at 5:00 PM", settings={'STRICT_PARSING': True, 'DATE_ORDER': 'DMY'})
for x in para[0]:
    date_time = x[0]
    date_string =  x[1]
    print(date_time)
```

Output:

```
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable
```

And also, this:

```
from dateparser.search import search_dates
para = search_dates("Competition opens 1/03/19 at 6:00 AM and closes 17/05/19 at 5:00 PM", settings={'STRICT_PARSING': True, 'DATE_ORDER': 'DMY'})
for x in para[0]:
    print (x(0))
```

Output:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Finally:

```
from dateparser.search import search_dates
para = search_dates("Competition opens 1/03/19 at 6:00 AM and closes 17/05/19 at 5:00 PM", settings={'STRICT_PARSING': True, 'DATE_ORDER': 'DMY'})
for x in para:
    date_string =  x[0]
    print(date_string)
    print(type(date_string))
```

Output:

```
1/03/19 at 6:00 AM and
<class 'str'>
17/05/19 at 5:00 PM
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tuple contains two elements as you have pointed out. A string and a datetime object.  For example

```
('1/03/19 at 6:00 AM and', datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 1, 6, 0))
```

- You can isolate just the string, by indexing the tuple.

#### For Example

```
from dateparser.search import search_dates
para = search_dates("Competition opens 1/03/19 at 6:00 AM and closes 17/05/19 at 5:00 PM", settings={'STRICT_PARSING': True, 'DATE_ORDER': 'DMY'})
for x in para:
    date_string =  x[0]
    print(date_string)
```

You may also want to remove the **'and'** from the text. You can do this by stripping it. I.e

```
date_string = x[0].strip('and')
```

#### output

```
1/03/19 at 6:00 AM 
17/05/19 at 5:00 PM
```

If you only ever want to use the strings and want to discard the datetime completely, use a list comprehension to create the **para** variable. In the example below, para populated with just a list of strings rather than tuples. The datetime is discarded completely

```
para = [d[0] for d in search_dates("Competition opens 1/03/19 at 6:00 AM and closes 17/05/19 at 5:00 PM", settings={'STRICT_PARSING': True, 'DATE_ORDER': 'DMY'})]
print(para)
# Output is just a 1D list of strings
# ['1/03/19 at 6:00 AM and', '17/05/19 at 5:00 PM']
print(para[0].strip('and'))
# Output is first string in the list with 'and' stripped off
# 1/03/19 at 6:00 AM
```

Comment: Hope that helps

Comment: Cheers- And, of these, how would I obtain the output of one of the dates i.e. 1/03/19 at 6:00 AM?

Comment: @ConnorJames I've added another section for if you want to just discard the datetime completely. You can use a list comprehension to build a  list of just the strings. Then you can index them as you wish

Comment: Perfect. I appreciate your help.